# Diffrence between HTML collection & an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Following code produces nothing but an error. I wish to retrieve REL attribute values of each of the DIVs. No idea, why I can'y do it.

Error I see in console: ***Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAttribute'***

```
    <div class="boxes">
        <div rel="first" class="box">Box 1</div>
        <div rel="second" class="box">Box 2</div>
        <div rel="third" class="box">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var i = 0;
            var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
            var arr = [];
            arr.push(allDivs);
            setInterval(function(){
                console.log(arr[i].getAttribute('rel'));
                i++;
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're pushing an array (NodeList to be exact) into an array and trying to get the attribute from the NodeList object instead of the individual elements. Try this:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div rel="first" class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div rel="second" class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div rel="third" class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var i = 0;
        var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(allDivs);
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(arr[0][i].getAttribute('rel'));
            i++;
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

By pushing the NodeList into the other array, you are essentially creating this:

```
var arr = [[<div element 1>, <div element 2>, <div element 3>]];
```

What you are probably wanting to do is to change your push line to:

```
arr.push.apply(arr, allDivs);
```

That will append all the individual elements inside the allDivs collection onto `arr`. Then you can access `arr` like you expected before: `arr[i].getAttribute('rel')` (arr's contents will be `[<div element 1>, <div element 2>, <div element 3>];`)

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` does not return an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Instead, it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList).

Comment: thanks for the distinction. it is important to know that the return value from getElementsByClassName is not a javascript Array, but a live collection, called a NodeList. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the script with this:

```
     $(function(){
        var i = 0;
        var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        //allDivs itself is an array and there is no need to push the result to an array.

        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(allDivs[i].getAttribute('rel'));
            i++;
        }, 1000);

     });
```